# POST image iOS to one server works and another identical servers gets 500 error

Tags: php, ios, image, post, http-post

ok i am banging my head against the wall on this one. I have a POST sending an image to a PHP page. It worked until I moved to a new but identical server: LINUX running the same version of PHP (5.3). If i change the URL in the following code to the previous server it works but as soon as i switch to the new one, it does not work. Here is my code. Does anyone have any suggestions? Does my post look ok? Does anyone see anything i could change?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // START NEW METHOD
    NSString *urlString = @"http://newserver";
    //NSString *urlString = @"http://oldserver";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // picture 1
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_image1.image, .10);

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image1.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set request body
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    //return and test
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Return String: %@", returnString);
```

Comment: Does the 500 error have any description with it?  Or, if you have access to the server can you see the log msg for the 500 error? Something sounds not so identical.

Comment: i agree something sounds not so identical. There really is no info with it and there are no logs. The site is hosted at go daddy. I had it all on a test site...then moved it to my real site and now it is not working.

Comment: this is what i get: <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 webmaster@mysite.biz to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>

Comment: Looks like you are uploading an image?  Have you run a simple <?php phpinfo(); ?> page on both servers to compare php flags such as upload size limit, uploads enabled, max file size, max upload size, max post size... PHP may be configured differently by default.  Also, check permissions if writing to a folder.

Comment: hmmm...i see a difference in max input time. New server is set to -1 and old server is set to 60. Doing some quick research it seems it MAY have an impact but i am not sure.

Comment: -1 may actually imply no limit.  I'd keep checking.

Comment: well i updated it anyway along with post max size but is still not working. I did manager to get a normal HTML page calling another PHP to upload a file and it worked. So i don't know why my POST from my app does not but that HTML page calling PHP does. ugggh

Comment: Is this resolved ? If yes then please let me know.I am having an exact same issue right now  :(

Comment: yes it is resolved but i am not sure what go daddy changed. The problem was definitely server side. You should call your host and tell them it worked on one server and not the other and have them check if they can see the difference.